# Remove all files except

Tags: deployment, find

Im running a deployment script on my current test environment but at other environments it is way too slow. Below script is running to remove all files and keep only the ones that have to remain:

```
# match all files except
find . -type f \
    ! -wholename './app/etc/local.xml' \
    ! -wholename './app/etc/jobs.xml' \
    ! -wholename './app/etc/monolog.xml' \
    ! -wholename './shell/amqp/ESBQueueReaderMonoService.exe.config' \
    ! -wholename './index.php' \
    ! -wholename './var/*' -a \
    ! -wholename './media/*' -a \
    ! -wholename './maintenance.flag' \
    -delete

# match all directories that are now empty ...
find  . -type d \
    ! -wholename './var' -a \
    ! -wholename './media' -a \
    -empty \
    -delete
```

The issue over here is maybe also that my `./media` is running as NFS share and the script is ofcourse also scanning that.

How can i improve this and have it deploy really fast. Or maybe even by using `locate` for example? I know there are some better deployment methods available but those are only planned for Q2 2017 so i have to stick by running it via sh itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try to provide an `-xdev` arg to `find` command
`find . -type f -xdev <other args>`
This will make `find` search only within current filesystem so it will not search your `NFS` shares

Comment: +1, you can also use -path and -prune to exclude a directory tree regardless of it being in another file system or not: find . -path ./src/emacs -prune would exclude the ./src/emacs directory (example taken directly from man find)